# Bash script with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm doing a curl from Cisco Meraki API and I only want the IP and the MAC address, so I'm modifying the file with sed. I also tried grep and the problem was the same, and I don't know how to solve it.

The script is the following:

```
curl -s -L -H 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: XXXX' -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/XXX' | json_pp >> dispositius.json

sed -i '1d' dispositius.json
sed -i '/description/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/usage/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/id/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/sent/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/recv/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/}/d' dispositius.json 
#sed -i '/[/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/{/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/]/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/mdnsName/d' dispositius.json  
sed -i '/vlan/d' dispositius.json 
sed -i '/dhcpHostname/d' dispositius.json
#cat dispositius.json | grep -E 'ip|mac' >> dispositius.json
sed -i 's/"//g' dispositius.json
sed -i 's/,//g' dispositius.json
cat dispositius.json
```

The result sometimes is the correct and I get the final file like this:

```
  mac : 58:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  ip : 10.XXX.X.XXX
  mac : e4:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  ip : 10.XXX.XXX.XX
  mac : c0:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  ip : 10.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

That is what I really want, but other times i get the final file like this:

```
  ip : 10.XXX.X.XXX      
  mac : 58:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  mac : e4:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  ip : 10.XXX.XXX.XX
  mac : c0:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  ip : 10.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I know using grep the code is very simple, but as I said above, the result was the same so I tried to change it. I don't know if its fault of my machine, of the connection or what.

Thank you

**EDIT: This is the output of the curl**

```
[
   {
  "description" : "android-c548dddc8a94ed69",
  "mdnsName" : null,
  "dhcpHostname" : "android-c548dddc8a94ed69",
  "vlan" : "",
  "ip" : "10.XXX.XXX.XXX",
  "mac" : "58:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
  "usage" : {
     "sent" : 31021,
     "recv" : 564
  },
  "id" : "k8b00e9"
 },
  {
  "description" : "bernat-ThinkPad-E560.local",
  "mdnsName" : "bernat-ThinkPad-E560.local",
  "dhcpHostname" : "bernat-ThinkPad-E560",
  "vlan" : "",
  "ip" : "10.XXX.XXX.XX",
  "mac" : "e4:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
  "usage" : {
     "sent" : 834738.922530264,
     "recv" : 54622.7158879327
  },
  "id" : "k8cdb55"
  },
```

Comment: If you show a representative sample of the response, then I'm sure your (very long) series of commands can be simplified significantly.

Comment: Are you sure that `curl` always puts out all fields in the same order?

Comment: The problem was what tou said @ThomasKühn . The request doesn't always put the fields in the same order. Thank you.

Comment: If my answer worked, it would be nice if you would accept it. This way others know that no further effort is needed to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry @ThomasKühn, i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting everything unneeded separately, why don't you do it the other way round:

```
sed -e '/mac\|ip/!d' dispositius.json | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g'
```

The `!d` instruction tells `sed` to delete everything that does not contain the phrases `mac` or `ip`.

Note that not all versions of `sed` necessarily support the `\|` syntax, but at least the `gnu` version does. On `osx`, for instance, you need to use `gsed` instead.

If the order of fields in the curl command is not always the same, you will have to sort the resulting pairs of lines. Assuming that you want the `ip` address first, you could do this:

```
sed -e '/mac\|ip/!d' dispositius.json | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g' | \
while read first; do read second; if [ "${first:0:2}" == "ip" ]; then \
echo ${first}; echo ${second}; else echo ${second}; echo ${first}; fi; done
```

What this command does is to split the output of the `sed` commands into pairs of two and sort them with a simple `if`clause: if the line with the `ip` address comes first, keep the order of the two lines, but if the `mac` address comes first, switch the order.